# Reference layout functions of igraph from a list

Tags: r, list, reference, igraph

I want to be able to reference a function from a list.
With this code I want to automatize the exportation of graphs with different layouts. I am using the igraph library.

The problem is that I get the text of the function instead of a reference to a function.

Could you maybe provide some code changes to make this work?

```
library(igraph)
g2 <- barabasi.game(100)
layouts = list(layout.auto, 
        layout.random, 
        layout.circle, 
        layout.sphere, 
        layout.fruchterman.reingold, 
        layout.kamada.kawai, 
        layout.spring, 
        layout.reingold.tilford, 
        layout.fruchterman.reingold.grid, 
        layout.lgl, 
        layout.graphopt, 
        layout.svd, 
        layout.norm)
for(i in layouts) {
    plot.igraph(g, layout=i, vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=3, edge.color="darkblue", edge.lty=3)
    dev.copy(png,paste("figures/network_v0.1_",substitute(i),".png",sep=""))
    dev.off()
}
```

Comment: did you try setting `layouts` to `vector` using `c("..", "...")`?

Comment: saving the function names in a list is an acceptable solution, and how do I then call up the function with name "fun1"?

Comment: could it work with get() ? let me try :D

Comment: you should construct a `layout` matrix for each layout for your graph `g`. If they all have similar parameters, then you can do something like: `do.call(get(layouts[i]), g, ...)` where `layouts` is a vector and `...` is the rest of the parameters you want to pass.

Comment: if you provide `g`, I might be able to experiment more (*always* provide *reproducible* examples).

Comment: @Arun I added an example graph..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you put the actual function objects into the list, then there is no way to find out their names any more. Function objects do not store their names, AFAIK. You need to make the list a named list, or simply collect the function names:

```
library(igraph)
g <- barabasi.game(100)
layouts = c("layout.random",
  "layout.circle",
  "layout.sphere",
  "layout.fruchterman.reingold",
  "layout.kamada.kawai",
  "layout.spring",
  "layout.reingold.tilford",
  "layout.fruchterman.reingold.grid",
  "layout.lgl",
  "layout.graphopt",
  "layout.svd")

for (alg in layouts) {
  print(alg)
  coords <- do.call(alg, list(g))
  png(paste("figures/network_v0.1_", alg, ".png", sep=""))
  plot.igraph(g, layout=coords, vertex.label=NA,
              vertex.size=3, edge.color="darkblue", edge.lty=3)
  dev.off()
}
```

Some remarks. `layout.norm` is not a layout function. `layout.auto` just calls one of the other layout functions, based on the size and other properties of the graph. You missed some layout functions, e.g. `layout.drl` and others. Here is how to list all of them and then you can filter out the ones that you don't need:

```
grep("^layout\\.", ls("package:igraph"), value=TRUE)
#  [1] "layout.auto"                      "layout.bipartite"                
#  [3] "layout.circle"                    "layout.drl"                      
#  [5] "layout.fruchterman.reingold"      "layout.fruchterman.reingold.grid"
#  [7] "layout.graphopt"                  "layout.grid"                     
#  [9] "layout.grid.3d"                   "layout.kamada.kawai"             
# [11] "layout.lgl"                       "layout.mds"                      
# [13] "layout.merge"                     "layout.norm"                     
# [15] "layout.random"                    "layout.reingold.tilford"         
# [17] "layout.sphere"                    "layout.spring"                   
# [19] "layout.star"                      "layout.sugiyama"                 
# [21] "layout.svd"
```

Comment: tnx, you nailed it. Now I can export high res graphs.

Comment: @frinx, you should also learn to upvote answers that are helpful.

Comment: bipartite can not be found, merge, norm and sugiyama throw an error

Comment: @Arun I just gained enough karma to be able to do so, patience ;)

Comment: @frinx, Sorry about that, but I meant for Gabor's answer :)

Comment: @frinx: then you are using a different igraph version, run the command to see what is available in your version and check the individual functions for the arguments required. As I said, `layout.norm` is not a layout function, neither is `layout.merge`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd do `do.call(layouts[i], list(g))` where `layouts` is a vector (as shown below) and `g` is your graph.

```
library(igraph)
g <- barabasi.game(100) #example graph
layouts = c("layout.auto", 
        "layout.random", 
        "layout.circle", 
        "layout.sphere", 
        "layout.fruchterman.reingold", 
        "layout.kamada.kawai", 
        "layout.spring", 
        "layout.reingold.tilford", 
        "layout.fruchterman.reingold.grid", 
        "layout.lgl", 
        "layout.graphopt", 
        "layout.svd", 
        "layout.norm")

for(i in layouts) {
    plot.igraph(g, layout=get(i), vertex.label=NA, vertex.size=3, 
              edge.color="darkblue", edge.lty=3)
    dev.copy(png,paste("figures/network_v0.1_",i,".png",sep=""))
    dev.off();
}
```

`layout.spring`, `layout.graphopt`, layout.svd`and`layout.norm` give error (probably it requires extra params). I'll leave that to you (as your question is about obtaining layout matrices within a function from a list/vector).

Comment: tnx for the help, I got it working. I will edit your answer to include the combination of the codes to form the answer I was looking for

Comment: you do not actually need to pass any parameters, its enough to just get the function by name with `get()`

Comment: Yes, then you're copying the function to another object and then you can run it with that variable, probably. For ex: `get(layouts[1])(g)`

Comment: @frinx, your edit got lost. I've managed to recreate your edit.

Comment: @frinx, still for some layout, this one gives an error. you'll have to figure it out.